# Dealing with subplots

Tags: python

Would appreciate the advice. Need to submit a figure with two violinplots on it.
Here comes the code:

```
figsize = (3.15,5)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

# Edit the font, font size, and axes width
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10
plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 1

# Draw a violin plot and save it 
x=['No','Yes']
l=[0.0,1.0]
ax1=sns.violinplot(x="Relapse", y="Age_at_diagnosis", data=df, aspect=2)
ax1.set(xlabel='Relapse', ylabel='Age at diagnosis')
ax1.set_xticks(l)
ax1.set_xticklabels(x)
ax2=sns.violinplot(x="Death", y="Age_at_diagnosis", data=df, aspect=2)
ax2.set(xlabel='Death', ylabel='Age at diagnosis')
ax2.set_xticks(l)
ax2.set_xticklabels(x)
plt.savefig('AgeRelapseDeath.tiff', dpi=300, transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight')
```

So I end up with the following figure:
[image]

What I would like to do is to bring the "relapse" violinplot to the upper box (now two are overlapped), have an x-axis label "Relapse" below the upper box and y-axis label "Age at diagnoses" in the upper box (just like in the lower box).
And also, if I want to save the output figure 8 cm wide with 300 dpi, am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the axis to the `sns.violinplot` function:

```
ax1=sns.violinplot(x="Relapse", y="Age_at_diagnosis", data=df, aspect=2, ax=ax1)
ax1.set(xlabel='Relapse', ylabel='Age at diagnosis')
ax1.set_xticks(l)
ax1.set_xticklabels(x)
ax2=sns.violinplot(x="Death", y="Age_at_diagnosis", data=df, aspect=2, ax=ax2)
ax2.set(xlabel='Death', ylabel='Age at diagnosis')
ax2.set_xticks(l)
ax2.set_xticklabels(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! Now it worked. Would you please also confirm that using my code I save it with 300 dpi and 8 cm wide?

Comment: You need to pass the `figsize` parameter to the `plt.subplots` function. Please, remember to validate the answer if it works, thanks :)